# Swipe pattern for broken screens?

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen

I had a swipe pattern lock set on my LG G3 phone. It felt down and the glass broke, so I cant use the touch screen any more.

Is there any way to connect my phone to a kind of a screen emulator, so that I can enter the pattern on a emulator and unlock my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a new [image: touch device] for a few bucks, unscrewed my phone and connected that with my phone. startover and entere swipe pattern and copied all my stuff.. DONE!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, you now have to enter your boot menu and wipe all data. This will remove the lock.

This URL might help

[Boot Menu](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi60_vmm_vRAhXGwI8KHbMWDEkQFgggMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftrendblog.net%2Fflash-twrp-lg-g3-using-bump%2F&usg=AFQjCNGDLgzzvdkPCW1lE8mm6HXsx_2MOg&sig2=THHm39WK6_74_S5XCSJhqA)